# How could I write this function recursively?

Tags: c, recursion, struct, hashtable

This is the hash table struct:

```
struct hash_table
{
  entry_t buckets[No_Buckets];
};
```

This is the entry struct:

```
struct entry
{
  int key;       // holds the key
  char *value;   // holds the value
  entry_t *next; // points to the next entry (possibly NULL)
};
```

What the function is meant to do is return the size of a hash table (how many !NULL entries it contains) but I am not sure how I should go about writing it recursively.

```
int hash_table_size(hash_table_t *ht)
{
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < No_Buckets; i++)
  {
    entry_t *current_entry = (ht->buckets[i]).next;
    if (current_entry != NULL)
      {
        counter++ ;
      }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need recursion for this task? I think the loop does the job just fine, given a few tweaks.

Comment: You could easily replace the `if(..) ...` by a loop, without the need for recursion.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Just for learning purposes and I thought this function would be the simplest one to try this on :).

Comment: How do you determine if a bucket is in use? (currently you are only counting buckets that carry a chain of offspring)

Comment: Use recursion only for problems that are inherently recursive (). In this case recursion make your code more complicated, more difficult to read and possibly less efficient. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: @wildplasser if its entry is not empty then it is in use

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes that is something I realised when I tried to do it myself but it is also something I want to compare with a recursive version of the function.

Comment: @davdavdav2 The array is fixed size. Entries are never *empty*. How do you detect that an entry is *in use* ?

Comment: @davdavdav2 try to write the factorial function once iteratively and once recursively using the definition `n! = n * (n-1)!` with `1! = 1`. this makes more sense than trying to force recursion on a typical iterative problem like counting from1 to n.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: It's funny, each time we ask someone posting on SO "why do you think you need recursion", they always answer "for learning purposes". But nobody actually knows _why_ they need to learn it. And there doesn't exist many reasons why. There exists multiple very good reasons why it should be _avoided_ however: dangerous, slow, memory-consuming, hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, recursion generally means that the currently active function calls itself with varying parameters.

So, if you wanted to implement the above loop as recursive function, it'd be something like this:

```
int countBuckets(struct entry *pEntry, int position)
{
     int count = 0;
     if (pEntry->next)
          ++count;
     if (++position < NoBuckets)
          count += countBuckets(++pEntry, position);
     return count;
}
```

This function takes the array of entries (hence the *), checks whether the first entry has a follow up item and then calls itself with the next item in line.

As I said in the comments though, 'the loop does the job just fine'.
As a side note, passing the condition is necessary, because otherwise you'd run into 'infinite recursion', making your program crash.

On a side note, if you wanted to count the members of a linked list instead, the code would need to change like this:

```
struct hash_table
{
  entry_t *buckets;
};

int hash_table_size(hash_table_t *ht)
{
    entry_t *entry;
    int counter = 0;
    for (entry = ht->buckets; entry; entry->next)
        counter++ ;

    return counter;
}
```

Or, if you REALLY wanted to do it recursively:

```
int countBuckets(entry_t *entry)
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (entry)
        counter += countBuckets(entry->next) + 1;

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: it could be even compressed to `if (entry) return 1 + countBuckets(entry->next); else return 0;`

Comment: Quite so, yes. Or, potentially, `return (entry) ? 1 + countBuckets(entry->next) : 0;`. There's (almost) always room for improvement. :)

Comment: Using `?:` is a bit obfuscating. Actually, I mean that the variable `counter` serves pretty much no purpose in `countBuckets`

Comment: Yes, you are right, @tstanisl. However, at the same time, I was once taught, that any function should, if somehow possible, only have one exit point. It's all a matter of personal style, really.